# Is it possible for a program to detect that another is directly reading its memory (using for example ReadProcessMemory)?

Tags: windows, memory-management

I was stumbling through public Github repositories when I came across a program (**A**) that displays information on screen based on whatever it reads in the memory of another program (**B**), an online PC game.

The `readme` claims that **A** does absolutely no writing to **B**, but also warns the user that some people have been banned from **B** because of **A**.

Now, it seems obvious that a program can detect if another program is changing its process' memory... But detect that a program is reading from it, for example by using [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) from the Windows API, how is that even possible? As far as I know, the process has no idea what happens on the system, unless you have some pesky "anti-cheat" software with high-level admin rights that monitor the whole system while slowing it down.

Could someone help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I remember reading on similar apps  fthey don't detect the reading they detect the presence of the app. Then under the terms ofif use of the game they ban you.

Comment: I see. So the game program is most likely run with admin privileges as well, to check other processes running, and running a program that has the same name as **A** could yield a ban even if it has nothing to do with **A**? Couldn't this be easily avoided by generating a random program name at every start?

Comment: It wouldn't need to be run as admin to be able to see processes running under the same user and most people run a (near) admin anyway. A process would be able to find the name of each program running, and check their on-disk location and possibly create a checksum of the program file. If that checksum matches a known version of the program then it could ban for that too. There are lots of ways to detect and prevent detection. The best way to avoid a ban is not to cheat in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The problem here is that this "readme" file, was created with the idea to distribute "A". And after "A" was distributed around long enough, "B" became aware that "A" exists, so it started looking specifically for "A".

IF "B" is not aware that "A" exist, It will have very hard time to detect "A", even harder time to distinguish it from "C","D","E" and "F", and it will be nearly impossible to understand what "A" is doing and take actions based on this.

Technically "A" can operate on many other levels, and read "B" memory by many other ways, than simple API call.

If anything, "A" can freeze "B", read what feels interesting, and just kill "B" after, preventing "B" from taking any actions.
(This is why "B" is usually guarded by "X", "Y" and "Z", running at the same time)

"B" can make it harder for "A", but there is NOTHING it can do to stop or detect it, considering the same amount of effort is put into both of them.